# Ionic 5: “ionic cordova plugin add” и “npm install @ionic-native/plugin --save”

Tags: npm, cordova, ionic

Возьмем к примеру этот [плагин](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number)
Устанавливается так:

```
ionic cordova plugin add call-number
npm install @ionic-native/call-number
```

> npm и cordova

---

Возьмем другой [плагин](https://github.com/rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin)
Устанавливается так:

```
npm install call-number
OR
yarn add call-number
```

> Только npm

---

Третий [плагин](https://github.com/cozzbie/cordova-phone-call-trap) устанавливается так:

```
cordova plugin add cozzbie.plugin.phonecalltrap
```

> Только cordova

---

Для чего в первом варианте используется и `npm` и `cordova`, почему нельзя использовать что-то одно?

*...забегаю наперед...*
Когда я буду писать свой плагин, могу ли я использовать что-то одно?
Если нет, то почему (скорее всего ответ в первом вопросе), если да, то что предпочтительнее `npm\yarn` или `cordova`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все Ionic плагины имеют два компонента:

1. Cordova: Нативный код (для разных платформ, например: Android, iOS).
2. Ionic Native: Обертка для соответствующего плагина (на JavaScript или TypeScript).

При установке вы делаете следующие:

```
// Установка Cordova (1)
ionic cordova plugin add call-number

// Установка Ionic Native (2)
npm install @ionic-native/call-number // или yarn add call-number (?)
```

---

По поводу примеров установки: самый правильный пример для Ionic плагинов, является первым. Так как сайт его генерирует автоматический на основе `plugin.xml`.

> Когда я буду писать свой плагин, могу ли я использовать что-то одно?

Да можете, но только `npm` и при условии что вам не нужен платформо-зависимый код.

---

Источники: [Ответ на EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686903/difference-between-ionic-cordova-plugin-add-and-npm-install-ionic-native-plu), [Ionic Community Plugins](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/community), [Руководство по разработке плагинов для Сordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ru/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html).